# How to set max integer value as TextBox value

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I have a TextBox with regex validation. It will be for counting days in a year,so I wanna set max value to 366. I wrote LINQ for it,but somehow It always get back false. If I exceed It and my validation turn to false,I want the program to set the max value automatically in my false statement. My code:

XAML:

```
<TextBox PreviewTextInput="Num" MaxLength="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="300,130,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140" Name="tNum" TextChanged="tbNum_TextChanged"/>
```

Please help me :)

Comment: Short answer is to find and use one of the many NumericUpDown controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the key down event and check if the content of your textbox + the key that was pressed is more than 365

```
private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
       //write your validating 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx solved.My code was ok,only the Textchanged event "bugged" it for me. With KeyDown or LostFocus it is working!

Comment: You are welcome.The reason why your code dont works with the textchanged event is because it gets triggert after youre leaving the textbox.

Comment: So what happens if the user doesn't hit the enter key, but just clicks out instead?